# Regex on ByteArray that Starts With Either Or

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a regex with `bytearray`. I have the two kind of bytearrays as

```py
data1 = b'\xa0\xa0\xa0\x81\x01\x04\x07\x00\x00\x0f2\x8e\xa0\xa0'
data2 = b'\xa0\x81\x01\x04\x07\x00\x00\x0f2\x8e\xa0\xa0'
```

The difference between `data1` and `data2` is the `\xa0\xa0\xa0` (`data1` has triple `0xA0`) and `\xa0` (`data2` has single `0xA0`).

What I need is to get the data as is (starting with `\xa0` to the end `\xa0`) and a way to distinguish the data to see if it starts with triple `0xA0` or a single `0xA0`.

When I build the regex as

```py
matches = re.search(b'\xa0(.+?)\xa0', data2, re.IGNORECASE)
```

It works with data2. But I can't know if it's a single or triple data. And It doesn't work with data1 (it returns as `\xa0\xa0\xa0`)

What doesn't work:

```py
matches = re.search(b'\xa0\xa0\xa0(.+?)\xa0', data2, re.IGNORECASE)
matches = re.search(b'\xa0((\xa0\xa0))?(.+?)\xa0', data1, re.IGNORECASE)
```

How can I get the whole data with a regex and also check if it starts with triple or single `0xA0`?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Try `b'^\xa0((\xa0\xa0)?.+?)\xa0'`. Once the match is obtained, check if Group 2 is not *None*, and if it is None, it is data type 2, else, type 1. Well, the regex might be `b'^\xa0(\xa0\xa0)?(.+?)\xa0`, too. It depends on what exactly you need to get in the end.

Comment: That's such a good answer. I was actually checking matches, ashamed to tell that I forgot to check group 2.  Thanks Wiktor...

Comment: But which is the right one, first or second? Does the match always happen at the start of string?

Comment: I think both would work, but the second one seems more stable enough. I'm still testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an additional capturing group to capture two more `\xa0` and once there is a match, check the group. If it is *None*, this is Type 2, else, it is Type 1:

```py
b'^\xa0(\xa0\xa0)?(.+?)\xa0'
```

In Python:

```py
import re
rx = b'^\xa0(\xa0\xa0)?(.+?)\xa0'
m = re.search(rx, data1, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    if m.group(1):
        print("This is data of Type 1")
    else:
        print("This is data of Type 2")

# => This is data of Type 1
```

I assume your matches happen at the start of string. If it is not always the case, you will need to replace `^` with a negative lookbehind:

```py
b'(?<!\xa0)\xa0(\xa0\xa0)?(.+?)\xa0'
```

The `(?<!\xa0)` pattern is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if the current location is immediately preceded with the lookbehind pattern (`\xa0` is a soft/non-breaking space).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification of your first regex that:

- uses a greedy match (`.+`) instead of non-greedy(`.+?`), and to start; and
- looks for 1-3 `\xa0`, whichever is longer, to start the string.

Your first regex doesn't work because, being non-greedy, captures the
shortest string between `\xa0` and the next `\xa0`, which is just
`\xa0\xa0\xa0`. After you can use `startswith` to see which kind of data it is:

```
# get contents
matches = re.search(b'\xa0{1,3}(.+)\xa0', data`, re.IGNORECASE)

# check type
is_like_data1 = data1.startswith(b'\xa0'*3)
```

Comment: This is a good way actually, I'm not sure why I didn't think of this :) Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

Your solution of

```py
matches = re.search(b'\xa0\xa0\xa0(.+?)\xa0', data2, re.IGNORECASE)
```

does work, however, you've applied it on `data2` rather than `data1`.

That regex will find a match for `data1`, but not for `data2`, like intended. You can use this regex first. If it matches, it'll be the "triple". Then, you can apply the more general regex on the remaining bytearrays, and if they match, they'll be the "singles".